# Why is `fprintf/sprintf` not working on `keypressfcn`?

Tags: octave, keypress

I was trying to type keyboard characters to a text file while my figure is open so I wrote down below code. Am I missing something ? (also tried with `fprintf`) Thank you very much

```octave
function myGUI()
    h.Mainfrm = figure("position", [200 200 200 200]);
    set(h.Mainfrm, "keypressfcn", @keypressCallback);
endfunction

function keypressCallback(hObject, eventdata)
    data  = eventdata;
    mystr = data.Character;
    fid   = fopen("mytext.txt");

    sprintf("%s" ,mystr)
    fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write into a file.

```octave
fprintf( fid, '%s', mystr );
```

Presumably you were using fprintf as `fprintf( '%s', mystr )` which simply writes to the default output, which is your terminal.

Furthermore, the file you are writing to needs have been opened as 'writable'! Or, in your case, since it seems you want to write character by character and append each character to your file, you need to open it with the 'append' flag:

```octave
fid = fopen( 'mytext.txt', 'a');
```

---

Btw, since all you're printing is a string, you don't need to specify `'%s'` at all, just print your string directly:

```octave
fprintf( fid, mystr );
```

If you want to do some sanity checking as well, capture the output of fprintf, which tells you how many characters have been saved into the file.

```octave
Output = fprintf( fid, mystr );
if Output == 0; fprintf( 'Nothing written to file\n' ); endif
```

Also, note that fprintf does not terminate your strings with a newline. If you want a newline and your `mystr` does not have one at the end, then you need to specify one explicitly, i.e.:

```octave
fprintf( fid, '%s\n', mystr );
```